# Kotlin change menu item title doesn't work

Tags: android, kotlin

```
 val menuitem=menuList!!.findItem(R.id.adres)
        menuitem.setTitle("asdklzmfkldfvsas")
        this.invalidateOptionsMenu()
        Toast.makeText(this,menuitem.title.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()



override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.gecmissiparis, menu);
        this.menuList=menu
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
```

here is My Code .
in `Toast`  it says title is changed but the titletext doesnt change or when i try to make it invisible it doesnt go invisible
i take the menu.xml from another xml not in the mainactivity.xml is this the problem? if yes how can ı solve it?

And that is the menu xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/itemxd"
        android:title="Item" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/sipariscx"
        android:title="Item"

        >
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/adres"
                android:title="czxzczxc" />
        </menu>
    </item>
    <item android:title="siparis1">
        <menu>
            <item android:title="adres1" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

NavigationView SEction

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView

    android:id="@+id/oldsip"

    app:headerLayout="@layout/haderdeneme"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/gecmissiparis"


    >
```

Comment: the changing of the text needs to happen inside of onCreateOptionsMenu

Comment: tried,no thing has changed

Comment: Are you sure`R.id.adres` is the id of the item you are wanting to update?

Comment: yep ı doublechecked i edited the post for xml you can check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just find menu item from menu in `navigationview` and update title.

```
val navView = findViewById(R.id.Navviewid) as NavigationView
var menuItem = navView.menu.findItem(R.id.adres)
menuItem.title = "New Title"
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `invalidateOptionsMenu` it call `onCreateOptionsMenu` again and new menu will be recreated and whatever changes you did in menu will be lost

try updating menuitem inside `onCreateOptionsMenu` method

```
var updateTitle = true
this.invalidateOptionsMenu()
Toast.makeText(this,menuitem.title.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()



override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.gecmissiparis, menu);
        this.menuList=menu
        if(updateTitle)
        { 
            val menuitem=menuList!!.findItem(R.id.adres)            
            menuitem.setTitle("asdklzmfkldfvsas")
            updateTitle = false
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
```

Comment: i edited my post in xml i add main activity xml's nav section. Toast gives the new title but screen doesnt change